# Clipping a raster via mask on runtime before uploading into GeoServer

Tags: python, gdal, clip, rasterio, extract-by-mask

I have point data which is being interpolated and a raster is generated. The raster is a rectangular grid and I need the raster of Pakistan only. I'm using shapefile of Pakistan to specify the bounds of clipping. The clipped raster contains the area outside Pakistan with zero value. Actually I want nothing outside Pakistan. I just need interpolated raster inside Pakistan.
I'm using Python. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [Edit] the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your code, it is very hard to figure out an answer, but this happened to me too when I was trying to do a similar thing in QGIS. What fixed my issue there was that I assigned a NODATA value. Is that an option in your code?